# How to determine if points lies inside rectangle?

Tags: c, points, rectangles

I am working on an assignment where I have to create a program for users to input coordinates for a rectangle.

This program is intended to be a struct within a struct.

If invalid, I have to output an error message and let user try again, indefinitely, until the user gets it right.

The program should repeatedly ask users for coordinates of a point, and the program will quit when user enters 0 and 0 for x and y respectively.

The program has to say whether the point is inside or outside the rectangle, and print out inside ones. I also need to figure out where to put the main function, and what to put in it. 
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
int x;
int y;
} point_t;

typedef struct
{
point_t upper_left;
point_t lower_right;
} rectangle_t;

int is_inside (point_t* pPoint, rectangle_t* pRect)
{
return ((pPoint->x >= pRect->upper_left.x ) &&
(pPoint->x <= pRect->lower_right.x) &&
(pPoint->y >= pRect->upper_left.y ) &&
(pPoint->y <= pRect->lower_right.y));

}

point_t get_point(char* prompt)
{
point_t pt;
printf("Given a rectangle with a side parallel to the x axis and a series of points on          the xy plane this program will say where each point lies in relation to the rectangle. It   considers a point on the boundary of the rectangle to be inside the rectangle\n");
printf ("Enter coordinates for the upper left corner\n");
printf ("X: ");
scanf ("%d", &pt.x);
printf ("Y: ");
scanf ("%d", &pt.y);

return pt;
}

rectangle_t get_rect(char* prompt)
{
rectangle_t rect;
printf (prompt);
rect.upper_left = get_point("Upper left corner: \n");
rect.lower_right = get_point("Lower right corner: \n");

return rect;
}
int main(){
/* calls goes here */
return 0;
}
```

Edit: I added main, but I don't  know how to make calls the functions.

Comment: You already have the function implemented `is_inside` and it seems okay. What is your question again?

Comment: The OP probably needs to know how to sew all this together. So as as hint: Add `int main () {  /* my calls go here */  return 0;}` to the end of your source file, then compile and link.

Comment: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KqzYWFZ5) Here's the source file.

Comment: there is some error for y-axis logic in function is_inside(..)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to modify a bit your style, and apply something like this:

1. Declare the prototypes of the functions before the main.
2. I think that you don't need to use pointers (reference pass
   functions) for most of your functions as `is_inside`, cause they won't modify the
   values .
3. Declare the rectangle points as point types (cause in fact you are using them as points).

To make calls, you just need to fill the arguments of the functions inside your main.
Example:

```
/* Headers, libs, definitions, etc must be here */
/* Prototypes must be here */

int main (void)
{
    /* Variables declarations */
    int test_point;
    point_t point;
    rectanle_t rectangle;

    /* Functions calls... */
    /* holder = function_name( argument1, argument2 ); */

    test_point = is_inside( &point, &rectangle ); 


}
/*Function Declarations must be here*/
```